# Android: Fragment: Why can i only get a reference to a view in the onCreateView method?

Tags: java, android

i am a newbie and currently learning java.
After opening a `Fragment` over my `MainActivity`, i wanted to change a View in the `Fragment`.
I noticed that i cant just use `findViewById(R.id.viewNameInXml)` in a freely choosen method like i do in my `MainActivity`. After searching for a while, i found the solution to get the reference to the View:
I had to change the `onCreate()` method of the `Fragment` to the following:

```
View inf = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_name, container, false);
TextView tv = (TextView)   
inf.findViewById(R.id.textViewIdXml);
zv.setText("new text");
return inf;
```

My question is: Why can i only access the `TextView` this way? Please keep in mind that i am a beginner, so try to keep it simple please-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that you can only access it in `onCreateView`, it's that this method is a convenient place to use `findViewById()` and save references to some of those Views. You could also use `onViewCreated` for this.

Why are these two methods convenient for accessing the Views? `Fragment` doesn't have a `findViewById` method, so you need a View on which to call that method. In `onCreateView`, you are already inflating the view hierarchy, so you have a View; in the second, the root view of the view hierarchy is passed as a method parameter, so again you have a View.

Outside of these two methods, you can obtain the `Fragment`'s root View by calling `getView()`, but be warned that this can return `null` depending on when it is called because of the `Fragment` lifecycle. (The methods above are both lifecycle methods, by the way.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now i understand why i cant just call findViewById alone. Would i call "this.getView()" in the Fragment outside of these 2 methods?

Comment: @Fr4nkWh1te Yes, and you don't even need the `this.`. That said, it's common practice to use one of the two lifecycle methods to store references to an views you plan to manipulate later, so that's what I would recommend.

Answer (score 1):

> Why can i only access the TextView this way

Mostly because you are yet about to learn class members in Java :) Nothing prevents you from moving `View inf;` out of the `onCreateView`. You only need to assign it there but once it's done you can use it elsewhere.

Comment: Ok i understand. That helps me to access the view elsewhere in the future. The only question left is, why do i even have to call findViewById ON "inf"? Why cant i just write TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtId) in another method like i do in the Main Activity?

Comment: My last comment's questions got solved in the 2nd answer, so nevermind :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need to find textview from the view / layout you inflated in fragment. In Activity you set layout as content to Activity which it inflates and holds the reference of the same internally. So you can use `findViewById()` directly here.

*Note: Using layout with Activity is legacy solution and were used before Fragment was introduced.*